# How does the additional damage from rend apply to DR?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, damage-reduction

All forms of rend, that I have seen, state that rend is additional damage. How is this additional damage applied? Is the "additional" damage added to the damage of the triggering attack, both attacks or is it separate damage as though it is a separate attack all together?

The relevancy of this question comes in to account in how it reacts with DR. By the description of the ability the two attacks combine to tear the flesh essentially making it one massive wound. I doubt both attacks and the rend damage combine for one solid hit, however that is how the wording makes it sound to me.

As always any material references via copy and past, links or sections/page numbers are preferred and appreciated in supporting your answers.

In Addition for purposes of Power Attack would rend qualify as melee damage and grant additional damage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[James Jacobs says](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kc7z?Rend-Power-Attack#10) it adds to the damage of the triggering attack (typically, the second claw that hits, though it varies by monster), which is also how the Two-Weapon Rend feat works, meaning that it does not apply DR again nor Power Attack again (nor Sneak Attack or on-hit effects like *flaming*), because it's just bonus damage on the attack.

Comment: I tried following the thread in the link - seems like James Jacobs says that the DR *is* applied to the rend additional damage - see [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kc7z?Rend-Power-Attack#16)

Comment: It adds damage to the triggering attack, so if the triggering attack is entirely absorbed by the DR, the remaining DR will apply to the rend, if you want to think of it that way.  Basically the damage calculation becomes (claw damage [with bonuses from STR and Power Attack]+ rend damage [with bonus from STR]) - DR = final damage.  He does wish-wash a bit in that thread though.  http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kc7z&page=2?Rend-Power-Attack#52

Comment: So the full calculation (hiding other damage modifiers for readability) is: (first claw damage - DR) + (second claw damage + rend damage - DR) - right?

Comment: Yes, that's both how I read Mr. Jacob's answers and how I believe it works by RAW.

Comment: I realise this answer is quite old, but there is an FAQ *[that was released prior to this answer](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fq#v5748eaic9qy7)* that implies that Rend does in fact gain the benefit of Power Attack because it is an *additional damage **roll***, and not an add-on to a previous attack. I believe this means the provided answer is incorrect.

Comment: @royalmurder PFS rules deviate enough from core Pathfinder rules that I'm not particularly concerned with them if the question isn't tagged [pathfinder-society].  It likely wouldn't hurt anything to use their version and let Power Attack apply twice, especially if you're letting DR apply to it separately as well.  But a PFS clarification is just a "house rule" for that campaign, not an errata for non-PFS play.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, sorry; wasn’t aware PFS clarifications only applies there.